# What are the objective differences between what's real and what's fake?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language

If someone makes a copy of Mona Lisa, why is this "Mona Lisa" a fake Mona Lisa, and not a real Mona Lisa? Why would copies be fake?

If someone "creates" something they call an "eyeball" in laboratory setting, that looks, feels and functions like an eyeball, why would this something be a fake "eyeball", and not a real eyeball?

If someone "creates" something they call "meat" in laboratory, that looks, feels, tastes and functions like meat, why would this something be fake "meat", and not real meat?

Etc, etc. There are many questions I can ask that are similar to this

Comment: If someone makes a copy of the Mona Lisa, it's a genuine copy. You are using "original" and "copy" as real and fake. The original is the original, the copy is the copy. They're both genuine. It's a common semantic inaccuracy. With the eyeball, it's natural or man-made. They're both genuine. A genuine natural eyeball and a genuine man-made eyeball.

Comment: In your examples, at least, there is no need for "objective" originality and fakeness. A fake is a fake simply because it does not share the *relevant* property of the original, which for Mona Lisa is - to be made by Leonardo. But relevance is not "objective", it is relative to a purpose, and for many purposes (e.g. educational) a copy may do just fine. However, copies are limited to what the copier knows about the original, and for those interested in discovering things not yet known (or even just leveraging potential for it) the copy simply fails to be relevantly similar to the original.

Comment: Regarding the more interesting issue about e.g. "meat", see [Natural Kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/)

Comment: fake = purporting to be something it isn't.

Comment: Please be aware that questions and answers are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Anything closed can be edited to bring it within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [MetaPhil](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You might be interested in functionalism, the idea that objects are defined, not by essence, but by their interactions with each other. I.e. If something tastes, smells, feeds like meat, then by all means it's meat.

Comment: @armand ... And what's the opposite of functionalism? That's what I would be interested in. The opposite in which "something tasting, smelling, and feeling like meat" still doesn't make it meat.

Comment: Not sure there is a specific opposite of functionalism. Plato thought things were imperfect embodiment of perfect ideas, so those things would have an "essence" that is defining them, however they may interact with other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is some absolute contrast between 'real' and 'fake'.  Like most of these things it depends on the context.  And on the question 'A real what?'

For instance, a model of a horse is real.  It's a real model of a horse.  It's not a fake model of a horse.  One could say, I suppose, that it is a fake horse.

With the Mona Lisa, there is the issue of authenticity and origination.  The value of the original Mona Lisa stems from the fact that it was painted by Leonardo, and only about 10 Leonardos survive.  An exact copy is a real picture, and a real copy of the Mona Lisa.  But it wasn't painted by Leonardo, and this is why we would call it a fake.  Even if someone made an identical copy, there remains a certain cachet to the original.  It is more 'authentic' so more 'real' in that sense.  But it is not more absolutely real.  All real things are as real as one another.

Something similar is going on with meat.  We have a sense of 'real' meat that comes from a living animal, in the same way that the 'real' Mona Lisa came from Leonardo.  This makes artificial meat fake, in that sense.  But artificial meat is still real (i.e. real artificial meat) and, perhaps bio-chemically, it is exactly like real meat.  But it would still be fake in the sense of not being from an animal.

Comment: Basically I agree... But the issue is not with "common sense" but with purported philosophical issues. An "identical copy" is a nonsense: if it has been copied, this means that has been produced after the original (maybe with the author of the copy having the original in front): thus it cannot be identical (spazio-temporal difference, etc.).

Comment: Having said that, the issue with "meat" is more interesting and it is becoming relevant with today "artificial meat". We can legislate (in principle... in practice language does not change that way) about the use of the word "meat" only after a scientific and legislative process that define if and to what extent we can "use" it in place of the "original". See e.g the EU debate between different countries about "chocolate" (a human artifact): how much cocoa is needed in order to call it "chocolate"? IMO there is no "metaphysical" essence that can help us: no platonic Form of chocolate...

Answer (score 0):

> If someone makes a copy of Mona Lisa, why is this "Mona Lisa" a fake Mona Lisa, and not a real Mona Lisa? Why would copies be fake?

What art amateurs are mostly interested in are the original works of art. This is an empirical fact and there is no use trying to weasel out of it. Language reflects what matters to people. The use in this context of the words "original", "copy" and "fake" goes back centuries. So, basically, you only need to look up these words in a dictionary to be able to reply to your own question. There is no deep metaphysical issues here. You only need to conform to usage.

So a copy is a copy and not necessarily a fake. A fake is called a fake if it is a copy of the original, not the original, and presented as if it was the original, which means that there is wilful deception.

Not just words, but also how people use them.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up on the internet and found a picture on an auction site that is at the same time a genuine Kujau and a fake Renoir. A genuine Kujau / fake Picasso has an estimate for 300 to 350 Euros. So is it genuine or fake?

I’ve seen fake china in a museum. 18th century forgeries of 16th century china. They are considered genuine copies nowadays and are worth many thousands. The originals are worth ten thousands.

Comment: Why are you asking me my own questions 